# Does there exist a real differentiable function $f$ with the following properties simultaneously?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

‎Does there exist a real differentiable function f with the following properties simultaneously ?‎‎‎‎‎‎

‎‎‎(a) ‎$‎‎‎‎\mathbb{N}\subseteq{ ‎D_f}‎$‎‎‎‎
‎‎
(b) if put ‎$‎f_n‎:=f(n)‎$ ‎and ‎‎$‎‎f^\prime_n:=f^\prime‎(n)‎$‎‎,then the sequence ‎$‎f_n‎$ ‎and ‎$‎‎f^\prime_n‎$ ‎are ‎convergent but   ‎$‎\sum_{n=1}^{‎‎\infty‎}‎‎f^\prime_n‎$ ‎is ‎divergent‎    ‎as ‎$‎‎ n‎\rightarrow‎\infty‎$‎.‎

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If $f(x)=\sin(2\pi x)$ ($x\in\mathbb R$), then:

- $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):f_n=0$;
- $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):f_n'=2\pi$;
- $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n'$ diverges.